# twitter typeahead.js without dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I want to use twitter typahead to provide autocomplete in my inputs. I installed it and it worked. But I have one problem. I want to disable the dropdown. Is there a way to do this?

And if not, is there another plugin which as capable of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css at the last of head tag:

```
.tt-dropdown-menu {
     display: none !important;
}
```